# Docs for setupCommands in vscode cppdbg launch json

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my vscode cppdbg launch configuration, I am using setupCommands like

```
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    }
]
```

I would like to add additional gdb setup commands like

```
set print repeats 0
set print elements 0
```

into my launch configuration

Where can I find some documentation about this?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find detailed documentation too, but here it is how I see solution

You can modify `launch.json` like this

```
"setupCommands": [
    {
       "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
       "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
       "ignoreFailures": true
    },
    {
       "text": "set print elements 0"
    }
],
```

Or you can use vscode debug console to interact with gdb. See example below:

[image]

Comment: Here's some documentation that I have found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/launch-vs-schema-reference-cpp?view=msvc-170#launch_setup_commands

Comment: @EtienneNoël That tells the names of the properties, not what their values can be.