# VSCode Is there a doc for setupCommands in launch json?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know it's been asked before: [Docs for setupCommands in vscode cppdbg launch json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278274/docs-for-setupcommands-in-vscode-cppdbg-launch-json) but not have any answers yet.

I'd like to know all options I can set in "setupCommands" and find out if any of them are useful to me.

Does VSCode have such document?

Comment: if the doc is missing this you can add an issue to the vsc-doc repo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docs for setupCommands in vscode cppdbg launch json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278274/docs-for-setupcommands-in-vscode-cppdbg-launch-json)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the only doc I could find:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/launch-vs-schema-reference-cpp?view=msvc-170#launch_setup_commands